# What can I do to avoid tripping over HVAC drain line?

Tags: hvac, drainage

The drain tubes for the Furnace and AC run about 10 feet across the laundry room to the drain in the middle of the floor. Unfortunately this is a fairly high-traffic zone (seven people living in the house) and it is a bit of a tripping hazard. Does anyone have suggestions for different lines or something I could put around the line to avoid tripping?

Comment: what size, and material are the tubes?

Comment: One is 1/2" pvc, but the external diameter is closer to 3/4". The other is a clear flexible tube that's about 5/8" external diameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining it's only a 1/2" pipe, in which case maybe an on-floor cord protector might work: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-5-ft-Over-Floor-Cord-Protector-CDBK-5/100669770

Or you could re-route the pipe around the perimeter of the room to avoid the heaviest traffic.

Comment: That's a decent idea, and looking around along that line I found these that have a little bit larger channel -  http://www.cableorganizer.com/cord-protector-flexiduct/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution -- the one used in my house for both the condensing furnace and the dehumidifier -- is to run the drains into a small condensate pump. The output tube from this pump can then be routed up to ceiling level, across the room, and then down into the drain.

Comment: This is the best way to achieve what your looking for. You can have it pump to any laundry tub using a condensate pump. As long as you can live with the small noise of it turning on and off for a few seconds every time it needs to discharge.